# How to display values from form inside of a div

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms, input

I am trying to create a Library and add information that is entered into my form (form is in popup window) to appear in a div (bookCard) within my grid. I was able to create an eventListener for the submit button and make my div (bookCard) appear. However, I am unable to display the input from my form on the bookCard div. How can I add to the function to make the inputs appear and display there when it is entered? Is there something I am missing within the addBookToLibrary function?

Thank you in advance for your help.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!----GitHub icon-->
  <script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----------Font Below ---------------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jmq2vxa.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/open-book.png"/>
    <title>My Library</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="head-box">
    <h1>My Library</h1>
  </div>
<main class ="main-container">
  <div class="body-box">
    <button id="addBook">Add Book</button>
  </div>
<div class="books-grid" id="booksGrid">
  <div class="library-container" id="library-container"></div>
</div>
</main>
  <!-----Form information----->
  <div class="form-popup">
    <div class="form-content"
    <form action="example.com/path" class="form-container" id="popUpForm">
      <h3>add new book</h3>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="author" id="author" placeholder="Author" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="Pages" required max="10000">
    <div class="isRead">
      <label for="readOption">Have you read it?</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="readOption" name="readOption">
    </div>
      <button class="btn submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="invisibleDiv"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
/*CSS RESET*/
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


h1 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

.head-box {
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e0f3ff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

h3 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #27476E;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color:#ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192c44;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,#d0edff,#9DD1F1) no-repeat;
}

.body-box {
  margin: 3vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The pop up form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.form-content {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30vh; 
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid #001D4A;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.isRead{
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  border: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#invisibleDiv {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.books-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

/* BOOK CARD */

#library-container {
  display: none;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 28px;
}
```

JS

```
class book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
      this.title = form.title.value;
      this.author = form.author.value;
      this.pages = form.pages.value + 'pages';
      this.read = form.read.checked;
  }
  }
  
  //creates book from Book Constructor, adds to library
  let myLibrary = [];
  
  function addBookToLibrary(book) {
      const bookTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;          
      const bookAuthor = document.getElementById('author').value;
      const bookPages = document.getElementById('pages').value;

  }
  
  

  // User interface //
  const popUpForm = document.querySelector('.form-popup');
  const button = document.getElementById('addBook');
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  const booksGrid = document.getElementById('booksGrid');
  const bookCard = document.querySelector('.library-container');
  const form = document.querySelector('.form-container');
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
  
  // Form Pop Up function //
  document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').onclick = function()
  {
     popUpForm.style.display = "none"; 
     overlay.style.display = "none";
  };
  
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    popUpForm.style.display = "block";
    overlay.style.display = "block";
  });
  
  
  // Submit Button Event Listener (displays bookCard) //
  
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { 
    bookCard.style.display = "block";
    popUpForm.style.display = "none";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    addBookToLibrary();
  });
```

Comment: First make a demo book structure with tags and css, then clone that tag in js inject the data in it and then append it to the library container. But first update your code with that book structure / model

Comment: You should be able to just use your `bookCard` variable and set the `innerHTML` value, for example `bookCard.innerHTML = ""` and then fill in your `bookTitle`, `bookAuthor`, and `bookPages` variables. You might want to use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to dynamically bring in your variables.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion for using my bookCard variable was super helpful!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this out, it should help.

Good luck

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/bradtraversy/pen/OrmKWZ -->
```

OR

```
<!-- https://codepen.io/fun/pen/PPVwBY -->
```

Comment: I am happy that it helped! ^_^

Answer (score 0):

This is on-going, unfinish answer. The code in the question is put into live mode for investigation purposes.
Any reader may try to edit/run to get a solution.

```js
class book {
  constructor(title, author, pages, read) {
      this.title = form.title.value;
      this.author = form.author.value;
      this.pages = form.pages.value + 'pages';
      this.read = form.read.checked;
  }
  }
  
  //creates book from Book Constructor, adds to library
  let myLibrary = [];
  
  function addBookToLibrary(book) {
      const bookTitle = document.getElementById('title').value;          
      const bookAuthor = document.getElementById('author').value;
      const bookPages = document.getElementById('pages').value;

  }
  
  

  // User interface //
  const popUpForm = document.querySelector('.form-popup');
  const button = document.getElementById('addBook');
  const overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  const booksGrid = document.getElementById('booksGrid');
  const bookCard = document.querySelector('.library-container');
  const form = document.querySelector('.form-container');
  const submitBtn = document.getElementById('submit');
  
  // Form Pop Up function //
  document.getElementById('invisibleDiv').onclick = function()
  {
     popUpForm.style.display = "none"; 
     overlay.style.display = "none";
  };
  
  button.addEventListener("click", () => {
    popUpForm.style.display = "block";
    overlay.style.display = "block";
  });
  
  
  // Submit Button Event Listener (displays bookCard) //
  
  submitBtn.addEventListener("click", () => { 
    bookCard.style.display = "block";
    popUpForm.style.display = "none";
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    addBookToLibrary();
  });
```

```css
  /*CSS RESET*/
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
}


h1 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 8vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

.head-box {
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 20vh;
  border-bottom: 2px solid #e0f3ff;
}

h2 {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 5vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

h3 {
  font-family: ohno-blazeface, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 100;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 4vh;
  color: #001D4A;
}

button {
  height: 10vh;
  width: 20vh;
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 10vh;
  font-size: 3vh;
  background-color: #27476E;
  border-radius: 22px;
  border-style: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-style: normal;
  color:#ffffff;
}

button:hover {
  background-color: #192c44;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg,#d0edff,#9DD1F1) no-repeat;
}

.body-box {
  margin: 3vh;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The pop up form - hidden by default */

.form-popup {
  display: none;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  z-index: 9;
}

.form-content {
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  width: 30vh; 
  height: auto;
  border: 3px solid #001D4A;
  padding: 20px;
  background-color: #9DD1F1;
  gap: 10px;
}

.form-container {
  min-width: 20vh;
  min-height: 50vh;
}

.isRead{
  display: flex;
  height: 30px;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 2px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

label {
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 600;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

input {
  border-radius: 10px;
  height: 50px;
  margin: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 4px;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  border: none;
  font-family: poppins, sans-serif;
  font-weight: 300;
  font-size: 2.5vh;
}

#submit {
  margin-top: 4px;
  height: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  border-radius: 15px;
  color: #ffffff;
  border: none;
}

input[type=checkbox] {
    width: 20px;
    margin: 10px;
}

#invisibleDiv {
  position: fixed;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#overlay {
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
display: none;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

.books-grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(300px, 1fr));
}

/* BOOK CARD */

#library-container {
  display: none;
  height: 50vh;
  width: 50vh;
  border-radius: 15px;
  border: 5px solid #ffffff;
  background-color: #d0edff;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  margin: 28px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <!----GitHub icon-->
  <script
  src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/4c536a6bd5.js"
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <!----------Font Below ---------------->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.typekit.net/jmq2vxa.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
   <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="images/open-book.png"/>
    <title>My Library</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div class="head-box">
    <h1>My Library</h1>
  </div>
<main class ="main-container">
  <div class="body-box">
    <button id="addBook">Add Book</button>
  </div>
<div class="books-grid" id="booksGrid">
  <div class="library-container" id="library-container"></div>
</div>
</main>
  <!-----Form information----->
  <div class="form-popup">
    <div class="form-content"
    <form action="example.com/path" class="form-container" id="popUpForm">
      <h3>add new book</h3>
      <input class="input" type="text" id="title" placeholder="Title" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="author" id="author" placeholder="Author" required maxlength="100">
      <input type="number" id="pages" placeholder="Pages" required max="10000">
    <div class="isRead">
      <label for="readOption">Have you read it?</label> 
      <input type="checkbox" id="readOption" name="readOption">
    </div>
      <button class="btn submit" type="submit" id="submit">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>
  </div>

  <div id="overlay"></div>
  <div id="invisibleDiv"></div>
 </body>
</html>
```